# Aggregate sum of reduced array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document with an array of numbers nested a single level from the root. I would like to reduce the sum of the array and aggregate the total sum of all these arrays combined. For instance, in the collection below I'd expect to get back `{ votes: 12 }`.

```
{
  userId: 1,
  stats: {
    votes: [0, 4, 1, 0, 2]
  }
},
{
  userId: 2,
  stats: {
    votes: [0, 2, 2, 0, 1]
  }
}
```

I'm trying to reduce the sum in an aggregate pipeline but keep getting 0 or N*initialValue results.

```
{ $group: {
    votes: { $sum: { $reduce: { input: '$stats.votes', initialValue: 0, in: { $add : ["$$value", "$$this"] } } } },
} },
```

I've been looking at the Mongo aggregation docs for `$sum`, `$reduce`, and `$add` but can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by a constant value (to get a single document) use double `$sum` to get totalSum from all the documents. The inner one adds up all the votes for single document and the outer one adds up the results while grouping:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            totalSum: { $sum: { $sum: "$stats.votes" } }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4w0uD82WQVK)